# maven override project.version from command line

Tags: maven

I wonder if it is possible to override project.version/version variable in maven via command line?

The following doesn't work:

```
mvn deploy -Dversion=1.0-test-SNAPSHOT  
mvn deploy -Dproject.version=1.0-test-SNAPSHOT
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>just.another.company.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Module</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>POM Project for My Module</description>
</project>
```

Comment: why not just try a hello world project ?

Comment: @mebada, if I wouldn't try this several times on different projects I wouldn't ask. Why not just provide solution if you know it?

Comment: referring to Your pom, Simply you can't do that ... project.version should be static

Comment: `<version>${env.SOME_VARIABLE}</version>`, then `$ SOME_VARIABLE="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" mvn ...` Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Simply you can't override `project.version`.  Try:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=<version>
```

Usually, I start by updating the parentPom

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
```

This would be enough if the parent pom contained all child projects if not you will need to go to a super project that contain all child project and execute

```
mvn versions:update-child-modules
```

Also the two previous steps will be enough if the parentPom exists in relative path if not you will need to install parentPom project with the new version

```
mvn install
```

Usually this will be enough if you don't have module depend on another module. if you do, declare its version as a project.version like that and it will be reflected automatically

```
<version>${project.version}</version>
```

Check the [maven Versions Plugin docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: Works as a charm, but one thing I didn't mentioned... One of the modules is dependent on another module's artifact, so I need to override this as well. Just mentioned it, sorry.

Comment: Suddenly, this doesn't work on bamboo continious integration system. Have no time to ivestigate it, just providing fact. According to logs it hangs after the following: `Searching for local aggregator root...` So I assume it can't find parent pom...

Comment: Use `versions:commit` to remove de POM backup: `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.3 versions:commit` .

Comment: @mebada: this works flawlessly Agusti: you are right. mvn versions:commit is necessary to remove version backup pom files.

Comment: This is not usefull for me as it change pom.xml and my Docker build rebuild all every time even nothing has changed.

Comment: `mvn clean versions:set compile package` is not working because the version is only writen when the compile mvn operation was done. As result you build a jar with the former version (e.g. a SNAPSHOT) and after it you pom is changed. So 2 steps are required. 1st: `mvn versions:set` and 2nd: `mvn compile package`. But the question was if it is possible to do in one line. This e.g. I needed to do in Jenkins. The answer for this delivers the answer of John Velonis. Here you can do it in one line. I tryed it out and used immediately because I was searching for this solution.

Comment: **Note:** with this solution using `versions:set` the `pom.xml` changes on the file system and potentially needs to be committed to git. If we run this during a CI/CD pipeline, it leaves the git repository in a dirty state. For use cases where we want to dynamically update the version number from an automated build pipeline this answer should be preferred: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63384423/474034

Answer (score 39):

In Maven 3.5+, if you put the following in your pom.xml

```
<version>${revision}</version>
...
<properties>
    <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
</properties>
```

it will use 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT by default, but you can override it on the command line:

```
mvn -Drevision=2.0.0-SNAPSHOT clean package
```

**This only works if the placeholder property is called `revision` (you can also use `changelist` and `sha1` placeholders in your version).**

See https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: Somehow in multi-module projects with ${revision} in place I cannot build modules separately even when passing revision explicitly on the command line. The error says, that the build cannot find dependencies with the version ${revision}

Comment: Hm, according to https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#dependencies you have to use `${project.version}` instead of `${revision}` in the dependency and add `flatten-maven-plugin` to the parent pom, but I couldn't get it to work even when I did that.

Comment: Pay attention to the note that the name must be "revision". If you use any name other than the 3 listed mvn will print warnings that an expression is being used when <version> should be a constant and threatening that such "malformed" projects may not be supported in future.

Comment: From my testing, `${revision}` seems to work in the `project.version` and `project.parent.version` fields in any POM, but not in `project.dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.version`.  I assume it wouldn't work in `project.dependencies.dependency.version` either.  `maven-release-plugin` replaces the first two uses with the hardcoded release version, but leaves the other and it fails to resolve.

Comment: Very similar behavior with `flatten-maven-plugin` also.  I tried using `versions:set` afterward to fix up the dependency management entries, but Maven wouldn't let it run because the POMs were already invalid by that point.  Ultimately, this functionality doesn't seem to work with BOMs.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can override the project version by passing the required variable from the command line.

Make sure you are using the variable in your `pom.xml`

Eg:

```
mvn deploy -Dversion=1.0-test-SNAPSHOT
```

in `pom.xml`

```
<version>${version}</version>
```

This should get picked during runtime. If this approach does not works, can you please show how you are using them in your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work for me for some reason. Please refer to my pom.xml above.

Comment: It only works if you have the `${version}` placeholder ... uh... in place.

Comment: I'm facing the same situation, using Maven 3.x.x. The passed parameter will be ignored. Maven complains about the containing expression.

Comment: And what happens if you don't serve the version variable to you build process? Empty version or a string `${version}`. I think the approach is ok but better is the answer of John Velonis. It is more error tollerant.

Comment: Downvoted because ${version}, or any name but the 3 listed in John Velonis's answer, results in the warning from mvn noted by Reporter.

Answer (score -3):

Just use the [environment variables](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#properties):

```
<project>
    <version>${env.SOME_VARIABLE}</version>
</project>
```

```
$ SOME_VARIABLE="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" mvn clean install ...
```