# Can I force Maven to build a JAR even though POM packaging specifies WAR?

Tags: maven, command-line, jar, war, pom.xml

I'd like to build our project from the command line as a JAR without modifying the POM, which has the `<packaging>war</packaging>` configuration.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you would like to have the java class which are part in your war project to be packaged into a jar file?

Comment: Yes. I have the maven-jar-plugin configured to build a fat jar, but only when the packaging in the POM is set to jar. When we deploy to tomcat, we change it back to war. I'd like to be able to specify the project [POM] packaging type via a command line argument, but can't find information on doing this.

Comment: So this is something different. You can configure to run maven-jar-plugin as part of the build as supplemental step...but i don't know how you configured maven-jar-plugin to create a fatjar which is usually a job for maven-shade-plugin or maven-assembly-plugin which can of course made being part of your build but this results in changing the pom file....

Comment: Of course you can use simply `mvn jar:jar` but you have to be aware of that you configuration for your ueber jar uses the correct id `default-cli´ so this configuration will be applied on command line callings. If you are using Maven 3.3.X there are more options for this handling.

Comment: Thinking about "mvn -Dproject.packaging=jar" (which does not work as intended) is propably no option? According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100389/maven-override-project-version-from-command-line its not possible to overwrite version. so packaging is probably not either.)

Comment: If you use Maven 3.2.X or later you or set version via command line (properties) see [Release notes for Maven 3.2.1[(http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html).

Comment: @khmarbaise You were correct - I was using the assembly plugin for fat jar creation, not jar plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to explicitly build a jar while preventing the building of a war as well. But I realized I didn't have to. With this configuration of the maven-assembly-plugin, and the packaging set to WAR in my POM, a fat-jar and a war will always be created.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>myApp</finalName>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.company.app.Startup</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If this questions / answer seems confusing / not useful to searchers, feel free to delete it. Thanks to everyone who helped me get here.

Answer (score 3):

If you are free to chose how maven is executed it is possible to call maven to invoke the jar goal directly:

```
mvn jar:jar
```